# Can't pass a list of integers into object for Seeding purposes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

After updating the database these objects do appear, but the functions don't get added.

Here is the code to Seed some data (Tea's):

```
if (!context.Tea.Any())
                {
                    context.Tea.AddRange(
                        new Tea
                        {
                            Name = "Green Tea",
                            Price = 3.99,
                            FunctionIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 }
                        }, 
                        new Tea
                        {
                            Name = "Yellow Tea",
                            Price = 2.99,
                            FunctionIds = new List<int> { 1, 3 }
                        }
                        );
                        context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Here is the model for the Tea:

```
namespace Teatastic.Models
{
    public class Tea
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Price { get; set; }

        //Relationships
        public List<Function>? Functions { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<int> FunctionIds { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And here is the model for the Functions:

```
namespace Teatastic.Models
{
    public class Function
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Tea>? Teas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why does this part not work?

```
FunctionIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 }
```

ps: When I create a new Tea while the app is running, I am able to add functions to my tea through my controller TeasController (HTTP create-POST method).

Comment: you are able to add functions to your tea, so the issue is ?

Comment: `[NotMapped]` causing the issue, it wouldn't let you insert data which marked as `[NotMapped]`

Comment: @TinyWang although I am able to add teas while the app is running, but not trough the Seeder.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron but while the app is running, I am able to create them through my controller (HTTP create-POST method)

Comment: Its not quite clear what do you mean `"while the app is running`"?, Then when are you trying to seed data? Hows your `DbContext` configuration? If you remove `FunctionIds = new List<int> { 1, 3 }` while seeding, does it works?